# Problem with zoom on hover in CSS grid image gallery

Tags: html, css

I'm making a CSS grid image gallery. Image is zoomed on hover, but the problem is that it is zooming over other images. How to zoom it inside the grid?

Here is the code.
Html:

```
<div class="image-gallery">
    <a href="" class="img-1"></a>
    <a href="" class="img-2"></a>
    <a href="" class="img-3"></a>
    <a href="" class="img-4"></a>
    <a href="" class="img-5"></a>
    <a href="" class="img-6"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
        'img-1 img-2 img-3 img-4'
        'img-1 img-5 img-5 img-6';
}

.image-gallery a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15rem;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.img-1 {
    grid-area: img-1;
    background-image: url("../../../wp-content/uploads/2020/08/camera.jpg");
    min-height: 30rem;
}

....

.img-6 {
    grid-area: img-6;
    background-image: url("../../../wp-content/uploads/2020/08/accessories.jpg");
}

.img-1:hover, .img-2:hover, .img-3:hover, .img-4:hover, .img-5:hover, .img-6:hover {
    transform: scale(1.03);
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try adding a div around all the images and give it 'overflow: hidden;'

Comment: I tried that and it didn't help. I cannot find a solution for grid layout.